# Change of employer after 2 years working in Germany

Tags: germany, work-permit

I recently got a new job in Munich and it starts from the 1st of August. I have been working with my old employer (also in Munich) for more than 2 years now since February 2019.

In the beginning I got a work permit for one year (Feb 2019 to Feb 2020). Then I renewed my work permit in Feb 2020 and it was valid until Feb 2023. It says now in my work permit zusatzblatt that „Nach zweijähriger Dauer dieser Beschäftigung ist die Beschäftigung jeder Art gestattet“

So, my question is: Does this 2 year rule count from the start of my old job (from Feb 2019, in which case it's fine) or does it count from the issue date of my last renewed work permit, which is Feb 2020 (thus 2 years are not yet complete :/ ).

I have been working for 2 years for sure, but the issue date on my work permit is only one year old as I renewed it last year. Can I still switch jobs without any change to my work permit?

Comment: The text states: *mindestens zwei Jahren mit einem solchen **Aufenthaltstitel*** (residence permit), so the time 'with such a residence permit' is what counts and not a specific employer.

Comment: @Mark Johnson , the Text in my zustazblatt states : „ Nach zweijähriger Dauer dieser Beschäftigung ist die Beschäftigung jeder Art gestattet“

Comment: Please add that quote to the question.

Comment: If this is a Blue Card, then the following applies: [Section 9(1)(1) - Ordinance on the Employment of Foreigners (Beschäftigungsverordnung, BeschV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_beschv/englisch_beschv.html#p0053): *have been legally employed **subject to compulsory social insurance** in the territory of the Federal Republic of Germany for **two years***. So it is not based on a single employer.

Comment: No it’s not a blue card but a temporary resident permit till Feb 2023. So the section says :                                „“(1) No approval is required for employment of foreigners who hold an EU Blue Card or a temporary residence permit and who
1. have been legally employed subject to compulsory social insurance in the territory of the Federal Republic of Germany for two years „“                                                 So, I fulfill this requirement as I have been employed subject to social insurance for more than 2 years already. And I don’t need to change my permit I guess then.

Comment: Is this a **Fiktionsbescheinigung**, applied as a renewal of a Blue Card? (this is all relevent information that should be part of the question)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for sending me the Beschäftigungverordnung. I got my answer in Section 9(1)(1). It is an Aufenhaltserlaubnis not a Fiktionsbeschinigung . I have already served my 2 years of employment subject to social insurance so I do not need any approval according to the Verordnung.

Comment: On your zusatzblatt the employer name is still the old company?